time trend interaction
I have a panel dataset, and I want to perform some econometric analyses on it. I want to use a trend that interacts with the initial value of certain economic variables. For the trend, does it make any difference if I multiply my initial value by 1, 2, 3, etc., or by 1999, 2000, 2001, etc.? And how do you justify this instead of using the value of the economic variable over time?
Thanks in advance for your help!
